# string.Compare("KHA","KTB",true) return incorrect result in C#

Tags: c#

I am using C#, .NET 3.5. I have following code

```
string.Compare("KHA","KTB",true)
```

It returned value 1. This means KHA > KTB in alphabet order. 
I expect it returns value -1.

### Can anyone help me fix this?

Yes, all of you are right. It's because of the Culture. I add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and it is solved.
Thanks all!

Comment: That's right, actually. **H** precedes **T**, right?

Comment: In my system it returns -1. Could you re-check. Also try specifying String Comparisons [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx)

Comment: what is your Culture? the result could be right for your culture

Comment: I am also getting -1.  What language do you use / localisation ?

Answer (score 2):

[strig.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) returns **the relative position in the sort order**. <strike>Since 'H' comes before 'T' that is why you are getting `1`</strike>

Its should return `-1`, See the image
[image]

There must be something wrong going on with your compiler, it should return `-1` and your understanding for the `string.Compare` is right.

You may try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
int value = string.Compare("KHA", "KTB", true,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

The call `string.Compare("KHA","KTB",true)` should return `-1` as expected. It does when I test it.

If you get any other result, you either are using other strings, or you have a default culture where `'T'` is actually considered to come before `'H'`.

For the latter case, you can specify a culture info in the call:

```
string.Compare("KHA", "KHB", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really getting 1 against `string.Compare("KHA","KTB",true)` then your system's current culture must be making an effect. Check the documentation of [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxc48dt). Also check the best practices of comparing a string [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx#the_details_of_string_comparison).